# How to Object Array to List

Tags: c#, list, object

(C#) I have 2 classes. 1 is called Employee. The other is my "main". I am trying to take a list and assign each value in list to an array of Employee object.

```
//Inside "Main" class
int counter = NameList.Count;

        Employee[] employee = new Employee[counter];

        for (int i = 0; i <= counter; i++)
        {
            employee[i].Name = NameList[i];
            employee[i].EmpNumber = EmpNumList[i];
            employee[i].DateOfHire = DOHList[i];
            employee[i].Salary = SalaryList[i];
            employee[i].JobDescription = JobDescList[i];
            employee[i].Department = DeptList[i];
        }
```

This returns the error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Pgm4.exe
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I think this means that I am not calling the list properly. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You are just newing an array of type Employees, the elements in the array are all going to be null. You need to new an Employee object for each element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing that immediately stands out here. You are not declaring `employee[i]` to be `new Employee` at the start of each iteration therefore all other things aside, you will get a `NullReferenceException`

(Also as Marc Gravell pointed out, `<=` should be `<` to avoid an Index out of range exception...)

```
for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        {
         //actually create an instance of Employee in employee[i]
            employee[i]  = new Employee();
            employee[i].Name = NameList[i];
            employee[i].EmpNumber = EmpNumList[i];
            employee[i].DateOfHire = DOHList[i];
            employee[i].Salary = SalaryList[i];
            employee[i].JobDescription = JobDescList[i];
            employee[i].Department = DeptList[i];
        }
```

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly and it did thrown an index out of range exception.

Comment: @PeterBlack cool. Can I just ask though. Is there a reason why you don't use `List<Employee>` / generic collections in general for the solution?

Answer (score 3):

You have created an array with space for the *references*, but you have not created any `Employee` instances. All your `Employee[i]` are `null`. It should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
{
    var emp = new Employee();
    emp.Name = NameList[i];
    emp.EmpNumber = EmpNumList[i];
    emp.DateOfHire = DOHList[i];
    emp.Salary = SalaryList[i];
    emp.JobDescription = JobDescList[i];
    emp.Department = DeptList[i];
    employee[i] = emp;
}
```

or (tidier)

```
for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
{
    employee[i] = new Employee
    { 
        Name = NameList[i],
        EmpNumber = EmpNumList[i],
        DateOfHire = DOHList[i],
        Salary = SalaryList[i],
        JobDescription = JobDescList[i],
        Department = DeptList[i]
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As well as needing to create an instance of `Employee` for each element of the array, this line also has an error:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= counter; i++)
```

C# arrays are zero based so you need:

```
for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
```

otherwise you'll loop past the end of the array.

Your code should look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
{
    employee[i] = new Employee();
    .... // your existing code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Employee isn't initialized, add this to the beginning of each iteration:

```
employee[i]  = new Employee();
```

You are accessing an index that isn't allocated for you

replace this:

`int i = 0; i <= counter; i++`

with:

`int i = 0; i < counter; i++`